# org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property

Tags: java, spring, maven

Hi i am new for Spring and present i am running my application using Maven

but when i run my project i am getting exception like below

**'year' of bean class [com.ensis.spring.MovieLister]: Bean property 'year' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?**

### Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        MovieLister movieLister = (MovieLister)ctx.getBean("lister");
        movieLister.printMoviesByYear();
    }
}
```

### Movie:

```
private int year;
    private String name;

    public Movie(int year, String name) {
        super();
        this.year = year;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

### MovieFinder:

```
public class MovieFinder {

    private static List<Movie>moviesList;

    static{

        moviesList.add(new Movie(1990, "A"));
        moviesList.add(new Movie(1991, "B"));
        moviesList.add(new Movie(1992, "C"));
        moviesList.add(new Movie(1993, "D"));
        moviesList.add(new Movie(1994, "E"));
        moviesList.add(new Movie(1995, "F"));
    }

    public List<Movie>findMoviesByYear(int year){

        List<Movie>findMovies=new ArrayList<Movie>();

        for(Movie movie:moviesList){
            if(year==movie.getYear()){
                findMovies.add(movie);          
                }
        }

        return findMovies;
    }

}
```

### MovieLister:

```
public class MovieLister {

    private int year;
    private MovieFinder movieFinder;


    public void printMoviesByYear(){

        List<Movie>found = movieFinder.findMoviesByYear(year);
        for(Movie movie:found){
            System.out.println("So movies are======>"+movie.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

### applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="lister" class ="com.ensis.spring.MovieLister" autowire="byType">
   <property name="year" value="1991"/>
   </bean>
   <bean id="finder" class="com.ensis.spring.MovieFinder"/>
   </beans>
```

Comment: please try to add getter and setter methods for year in MovieLister class and check

Comment: Hi @avinash readdy  java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.ensis.spring.MovieFinder.<clinit>(MovieFinder.java:12)

Comment: now i am geeting above exception

Comment: where are you intializing your  private static List<Movie>moviesList ?

Comment: thanks @avinash redyy now i found problem

Answer (score 0):

Add a setter to MovieLister:

```
public void setYear(final int year) {
  this.year = year;
}
```

This is required because member variable year is private.

Side note:
If a MovieLister instance requires a year or any other member variable I strongly suggest to create a constructor that sets these variables.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.ensis.spring.MovieFinder.<clinit>(MovieFinder.java:12)

Comment: now i am getting this exception after adding your code

Comment: Is movieFinder set? I don't see it in your applicationContext or code. Maybe you meant to set moveFinder in applicationContext, but now it is only a bean and not set as a property of MovieLister.